# Azure Front Door Rule Engine, destination path too long

Tags: azure, azure-front-door

I am trying to configure a front door redirect using the Rule Engine. But my path, which is not in my control is very long. apparently the max characters for destination path is 100 characters.

Configuration:

I want to redirect URL which contain 'redirects/abc' to 'abc.com/aa/bbbbbbbbbbbbbb/cccccccccc/ddddddddddddddddddd/eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee'

[image: rule configuration]

I get the following error message Failed to update the rule set 'redirectionRules'. Error: Property 'Rule.Actions[0].Parameters.CustomPath' cannot be set to '/aa/bbbbbbbbbbbbbb/cccccccccc/ddddddddddddddddddd/eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee'. Maximum length for this property is: 100

[image: Error message]

Does anyone know some kind of workaround? Or am i forced to use something else?

Thx!

Comment: Is this an external redirect or an internal redirect to your backend pools?

Comment: Did you find a workaround for this? I have same requirement.

Comment: No unfortunately not, we just ended up using other paths